# How do I Make Particle Object follow Mouse Movement

Tags: java, processing

I want the particle object to simply follow the mouseX and mouseY location on movement. Can I replace the "origin" values with a mouseX and Y somehow?

```
  void run() {
    update();
    display();
  }

  // Method to update position
  void update() {
    velocity.add(acceleration);
    location.add(velocity);
    lifespan -= 2.0;
  }

    // Method to display
  void display() {
    stroke(0, lifespan);
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(127, lifespan);
    ellipse(location.x, location.y, 12, 12);
  }

  // Is the particle still useful?
  boolean isDead() {
    if (lifespan < 0.0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: You will want to read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first. This community is very helpful, but you have to play by it's rules! Also, post the part of your code which is relevant to your problem.

Comment: This is the smaller (relevant) part of a much larger block - and I have commented where the location items are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example is even simpler and easier to understand - hope it helps.

```
float x;
float y;
float easing = 0.05;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360); 
  noStroke();  
}

void draw() { 
  background(51);

  float targetX = mouseX;
  float dx = targetX - x;
  x += dx * easing;

  float targetY = mouseY;
  float dy = targetY - y;
  y += dy * easing;

  ellipse(x, y, 66, 66);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this example:

```
PVector pos;
PVector vel;
PVector acc;

void setup()
{
  size(400, 400);
  pos = new PVector(width / 2, height / 2);
  vel = new PVector(0, 0);
  acc = new PVector(0, 0);
}

void draw()
{
  background(255);
  followMouse();
  update();
  ellipse(pos.x, pos.y, 10, 10);
}

void followMouse()
{
  PVector mouse = new PVector(mouseX, mouseY);
  //calculating what acceleration would be needed to instantly reach the mouse
  acc = mouse.sub(pos);
  //reducing the acceleration to not reach the mouse instantly
  acc.mult(0.1);
}

void update()
{
  vel.add(acc);
  //dampening the velocity, so the ball gets slower when close to the mouse
  vel.mult(0.8);
  pos.add(vel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Processing's `lerp()` function is suitable for this (as you're looking for the particle to *lerp* towards the mouse cursor).

```
posX = lerp(posX, mouseX, 0.5);
posY = lerp(posY, mouseY, 0.5);
```

The final parameter (0.5 here) is the amount to interpolate between the two values where 0.1 is very near the current particle position; 0.5 is halfway in-between the particle position and cursor position, etc.

---

Lerp is short for linear interpolation. You may find other forms of interpolation (or easing) to be more suitable to model the movement of your particle, such those from the penner easing collection:

[image: Source: https://www.kasperkamperman.com/blog/penner-easing-functions-processing/]